# Difference between “please note” and “I would like to point out”

Tags: word-choice

Received an e-mail from a company I work with saying:

> Please note that. . .

Personally I prefer to say “I would like to point out that...”

Are both sentences correct?

Comment: Yes, both sentences are right, but they communicate the idea slightly differently. "*Please note that*" is generally used in the impersonal (think "omniscient narrator") voice to draw attention to a fact. It is used to frame the notation as objective. You could also say "*I would like to point out that...*", but that draws attention to *yourself*, as well as whatever you're pointing out, which tends to soften the impact ("*Please note that*" only wants to emphasize the fact as a fact; it matters not who identified it).

Answer (score 7):

*Please note* and *I would like to point out that...* both mean the same thing, that the speaker is trying to bring attention to whatever is going to come after. The difference between the two, as @Dan Bron pointed out in his comment, is that *Please note* is impersonal, while *I would like to point out that...* is more personal.

*Please note* is used when the speaker wants to make it clear that what he or she is about to say is important, and it is often used to give an air of formality or authority.

*I would like to point out that...* is used when you want to make it clear not only that you are making a point, but that it is *you* who is making that point. Drawing attention to yourself in this way makes the announcement seem less formal, and less authoritative.

In your situation, your company mostly likely used *please note* because whoever wrote the email wanted it to represent the company in general, and whatever the "note" is, it should be read as coming from the company as a whole, not any individual manager or employee.

Comment: "Please note" is correct but passive. A more direct alternative is: "Be advised"